# Why do we need complex analysis to connect two one-dimensional functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I noticed a fact about $\frac{x}{1-x}$.

$$ \int{\frac{x}{1-x}dx}=-x-\log(1-x), x \in \mathbb{C} $$

I was wondering: why do you need the domain to be complex numbers?

I both functions clearly have vertical asymptotes at $x = 1$, and I can apply basic calculus rules and check that everything works in one-dimensional calculus. I normally consider one-dimensional calculus to be connected to *real* analysis. What's going on here?

Comment: The derivative of $- \log (1-x)$ is $\frac{1}{1-x}$. Did you mean something else?

Comment: sorry, I did have the integral wrong. It's right now.

Comment: So, again, who said $x\in \mathbb C?$ It is certainly true as a real integral. If it was software that output the answer, then it was probably just noting the more general case.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It was Wolfram Alpha. Yeah that explains it.